# How to write a Java class following the SRP principle ? My specific case study

Tags: java, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am doing a small project/exercise in which among other things I have to create a html parser that evaluate a server-side script, give values to all variables in it -${ ... } -  and that´s all.

To achieve that I have written a single class called "Parser" that have 1 public method "parseHtml()" and a couple of private methods that do all hard work.  The issue comes when I think about one of the five s.o.l.i.d principles: SRP = A class should have just 1 reason to change:

I got not idea how to structure my class having to know that all private methods are called inside the public one. It is like a kind of facade pattern made into a method.

```
+ public parseHtml()
- private getExpressionsFromHtml() //method that grab all ${..} from the file
- private evaluateJavascript(script)
- private deleteJsSnippetFromHtml()
- private setValuesToExpressionsInHtml()
- private evaluateDataIf() 
- private evaluateDataFor()
```

Here there is a link where the author explain this principle of single responsability very well... but I still got some doubts about it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567768/Object-Oriented-Design-Principles

**So, what am I missing in this?**

When I write code, I tend to code following these sort of design: I define the related methods that a single actor is going to use, and then a sort of interface/public method  that deal with all of those mini private methods.   I always keep them as sort as I can a.k.a less than 20? lines per method, sometimes even 1 or 2 lines.

As you can see above the method´s names are as descriptive as possible to avoid write unnecessary comments.

Regards

**EDIT**

The aim of my application is that given an "index.html" I will be able to:
* Read the file
* Process the Javascript in that .html - Javascript engine - Rhino
* Parser the final html that will be render in the browser.

A servlet will take this program and will render the "parsed file" in the browser. The servlet looks like ...

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("index.html") ;

    Parser parser = new Parser();
    String screen = parser.doParseHtmlFile(path);   

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     
    out.println(screen); // Rendering page, is it ok with this?
}
```

Now I will list the classes that makes that parse possible. Just for the record, the parse is entirely done by using regular expressions, I have heard so many times that is not appropiate for Html due to nested tags but I guess for this little project/exercise it will do the work:

1. Parser.java

   ```
   public String doParseHtmlFile(String fileName) {
   /*Not sure if this method could be all extract into another class called for instance: ProccessHtml.  It looks to me like a Facade class?*/
        // readFile
        read.readFile(fileName);
       this.htmlParsed = read.getHtmlFile();

       // processServerSide
       this.attributesMap = processor.processServerSide(this.htmlParsed, read.getScriptSnippet());

       // parseHtml
       parseHtml();

       return this.htmlParsed;
   }


   private void parseHtml() {
   /*This method is the one keeping the responsability in this class of formatting the htmlParsed variable*/
   if( !htmlParsed.isEmpty() && !attributesMap.isEmpty() ) {
       this.removeJSFromHtml(); 
       this.setValuesToExpressionsInHtml();
       this.evaluateDataIf();
       this.evaluateDataFor();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Processor.java

   - public Map processServerSide(String file, String script)  // this method uses the list of private below - facade ?
   - private ScriptEngine processJavascript(String script)
   - private void getDataAttributes(String file)
   - private void evaluateDataAttributes(ScriptEngine engine)

   All those private methods relies on each other.  Which attributes are you going to evaluate if you don´t call first 'getDataAttributes'???
3. Reader.java

   - public void readFile(String filePath)
   - public String getScriptSnippet() // I get the Javascript section
   - public String getHtmlFile()      // I get the whole html

Comment: It's difficult to comment on your code without seeing it. Given your method names I'd suggest that there are a number of responsibilities in the one class - and that'd be your SRP problem. To solve it, you typically identify the multiple responsibilities and push them into their own separate classes. But without seeing more of your code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: I have already identified the responsabilities, which was not that easy and I will update for your perusal so I can proof myself whether I am or not right. Cheer sisyphus!